# Turning a string to an array

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using dependent LWC and from a lower level I am passing an array to its parent.
I first tried by hardcoding the array and that worked ok

```
@track testmap=[{'Id':'01t6700000Cwxot','Name':'Product1'},{'Id':'01t6700000CwxjY','Name':'Product2'}];
```

Now I am building this dynamically when some click happens and I build a string that I turn or try to turn into the format that works above but it doesn't.
I thought Split would do but I am wrong or doing something stupid that I can't see anymore..

How can I convert my concatenation into the good format of my testmap?

```
this.clickedAddSpot=this.clickedAddSpot+','+ "{'id':'"+this.record.prod_id__c+"','Name':'"+this.record.prod_name__c+"'}";
if(this.clickedAddSpot.substring(0, 1)==','){
    this.clickedAddSpot = this.clickedAddSpot.substring(1);
    console.log('title ' + this.clickedAddSpot);
}

this.selSpot = this.clickedAddSpot.split(',');
console.log('showRowDetails the array is :' +this.selSpot);
```

Here is the output in Java console

showRowDetails the array is :{'Id':'01t6700000Cwxot','Name':'Product1'},{'Id':'01t6700000CwxjY','Name':'Product2'}

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation instead of just pushing new items to this.selSpot?

Comment: @Adam, Simply because i am self learning and didn't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String manipulation should be the last resort.

```js
[{'Id':'01t6700000Cwxot','Name':'Product1'}, {'Id':'01t6700000CwxjY','Name':'Product2'}]
```

If the desired output is this one, the task would be a lot easier if you define an array then push several object.
You need an array (could be `selSpot`) and several object with two properties: `Id` and `Name`. You can build those object each time a user select the spot:

```js
selSpot = [];

yourMethod() {
    // something

    // Define the new object
    const clickedSpot = {
        Id: this.record.prod_id__c,
        Name: this.record.prod_name__c
    };
    this.selSpot.push(clickedSpot);

    // pass the array to the parent
    const selectedSpotEvent = new CustomEvent('meaningfulEventName', { detail: { selectedSpot: this.selSpot.map((elem) => ({...elem})) });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedSpotEvent);
}
```

Keep in mind that Javascript is case-sensitive, so `id` and `Id` are not the same.
Note that I deep cloned the array before passing it to the parent, this way the parent component cannot mutate the one of the child, nor its elements.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/events-create-dispatch.html#pass-data-in-an-event) (emphasis mine)

> JavaScript passes all data types by reference except for primitives.
> If a component includes an object in its `detail` property, any listener can mutate that object without the component’s knowledge. This is a bad thing!
> **It’s a best practice either to send only primitives, or to copy data to a new object before adding it to the `detail` property**.
> Copying the data to a new object ensures that you’re sending only the data you want, and that the receiver can’t mutate your data.

Please use meaningful names for variables, calling an array test*map* may confuse others

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a string, you can populate a list directly using `push`. For example:

```
this.clickedAddSpot = [];
this.clickedAddSpot.push("{'id':'"+this.record.prod_id__c+"','Name':'"+this.record.prod_name__c+"'}");
```

Comment: This way `clickedAddSpot ` would be an array of `string`. An array of object would make everything smoother

Comment: Agreed. I wasn't sure if they needed it as a string or an object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is JS.

You can use standard JS Objects and push them to your array.

```
this.selSpot = [];
this.selSpot.push({'id': this.record.prod_id__c ,'Name': this.record.prod_name__c})
```

When everything is added to the array you can get the String representation with `JSON.stringify(this.selSpot)`

Hope this helps :)